how to install a package for all conda environments?
I want to be able use a utility that installs using pip install regardless which conda environment I'm in. I've tried installing it in the base environment but it doesn't work: when I activate any virtual environment, the utility is no longer visible.
(base) :~/$ which aider
$HOME/miniconda3/bin/aider
(base) :~/$ conda activate env1
(env1) :~/$ which aider
(env1) :~/$ 

